# Error al redirigir mi dominio a una carpeta con una aplicación en apache2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, vps

Cuando intento cargar la URL de dmilanes.es aparece bookstack pero cuando intento cargar dmilanes.es/portfolio no me aparece. ¿Qué solución hay para que funcione correctamente ambos sitios al mismo tiempo? He probado de todo y no hay manera.

Proporciono capturas y como tengo los sitios configurados.

Sitio : **bookstack.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin dmilanestrabajo@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bookstack/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile     /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/dmilanes_es_b137f_f9845_1706717705_0a1607918228dc4fcce9d76ab7d0c3a9.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/keys/b137f_f9845_b68a77ab5bf6f2ffeacdec0c8bba7e01.key

    <Directory /var/www/html/bookstack/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews -Indexes
        </IfModule>
        RewriteEngine On
        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
    # Configuración para archivos específicos
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Este es el sitio donde tengo ubicada la aplicación bookstack que por lo general carga correctamente.

Sitio **portfolio.conf**:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin dmilanestrabajo@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile     /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/dmilanes_es_b137f_f9845_1706717705_0a1607918228dc4fcce9d76ab7d0c3a9.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/keys/b137f_f9845_b68a77ab5bf6f2ffeacdec0c8bba7e01.key

    <Directory /var/www/html/portfolio>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Configuración para archivos específicos
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

***Error :***

Cuanto intento cargar la url me aparece esta imagen y no entiendo el por qué le he dado mil vueltas.

[image: Error al cargar la url]

***Directorios :***

[image: Ruta de los directorios]

*Muchas gracias de antemano !!!*

Comment: te recomiendo leer que es un subdominio... adional si quieres que respondan a diferentes url la propiedad `ServerName dmilanes.es` ahora bien tu subdomain deberia ser `ServerName portfolio.dmilanes.es`

Comment: Los *VirtualHost* se estilan a nivel IP, dominio o subdominio; no a nivel directorio, ¿están hechos con tecnologías diferentes?.

Comment: Hola !! no están hechos con tecnología diferentes, tal vez me explicara mal, son directorios con aplicaciones. por ejemplo si pongo https://xxx.xxx.es/carpeta debería cargar la aplicación como tal, pero no lo hace correctamente.

Comment: He cambiado el titulo de la pregunta, ahora está correcta, gracias por la anotación !

Comment: Suena a que no necesitas dos VH, con uno cuyo *DocumentRoot* sea `/var/www/html` bastaría.

Comment: he probado con uno en /var/www/html/ pero me dice permiso denegado

Comment: Debe funcionar, revisa los permisos; según la documentación, *DocumentRoot* no debería tener `/` al final. Debes reiniciar Apache después cambiar algo en `./conf.d/`.

Comment: Listo ya lo he solucionado, era una tontería pero ha costado resolverlo !! me respondo a mi mismo poniendo la solución por si a alguien le sirviera de ayuda !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución al problema era bien simple, tenía que configurar un sitio por defecto y dentro ir colocando varios documentroot, sus configuraciones para los directory pego el código. Un saludo !

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # Dejamos por defecto este Virtual Host puesto que esta configuracion funciona correctamente
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>

           ServerAdmin dmilanestrabajo@gmail.com
           ServerName dmilanes.es

           # Varios DocumentRoot
           # Directorio principal para las aplicaciones
           DocumentRoot /var/www/html

           # Directorio principal para lanzar bookstack
           DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog/public

           Alias /gestor_de_bd /var/www/html/gestor_de_bd

           # Directorio para bookstack
           Alias /blog /var/www/html/blog/public
           <Directory /var/www/html/blog/public>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted
           </Directory>

            # Directorio para el portfolio
            Alias /portfolio /var/www/html/portfolio
            <Directory /var/www/html/portfolio>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>

            # Alias para el phpmyadmin
            Alias /gestor_de_bd /var/www/html/gestor_de_bd
            <Directory /var/www/html/gestor_de_bd>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>

            #Archivos para depurar y ver los errores cuando falla apache2
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            #Certificados ssl para el protocolo https
            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/dmilanes_es_b137f_f9845_1706717705_0a1607918228dc4fcce9d76ab7d0c3a9.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/keys/b137f_f9845_b68a77ab5bf6f2ffeacdec0c8bba7e01.key

            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```